# Table UI View : Mysql - Php

Tags: php, mysql

My Table View :

```
id  |   packetId    |   fweight    |     
1   |     002       |     150      |    
2   |     002       |     230      |   
3   |     002       |     200      |
```

But i want My Table UI should be look a like below 
:

```
id  |   packetId    |   fweight    |    sum(fweight)
1   |     002       |     150      |    
2   |               |     230      |   
3   |               |     200      |        580
```

I want to avoid that repeat (002) value , also fweight sum should be shown in another coloumn on last insert id.

ID - Primary id ,

How i can get this in Mysql , php .

**QUERY What i Know till now:**

```
"SELECT id, packetId , fweight from product where packetId="002" ";
```

Comment: Pretty hard to do in SQL. You better do that in your program logic.

Comment: @juergen : can you guide me for "program logic"

Comment: Your frontend (PHP) will do the trick.

Comment: @Christian : can you guide me how i can do the same in PHP , as i am still learning alot about php,mysql

Comment: No, we can't do it all for you. Try it and if you get stuck, add exactly where you are in your attempt and what the problem is. Then we might be able to help you

Comment: @juergen : i am not able to get it how should i start , thats why i have posted here for help :(

Comment: But this is not a step-by-step help forum. Take a tutorial. The rules here won't change. Sorry.

Comment: dude i am not asking for full code , just need your idea (logic) how i can implement same in frontend(PHP) .. as i am not able to think how i can do the same .. ok will search for same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have all the header file/conn etc.

Try this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, packetId , fweight from product where packetId='002'");

$tmp = "";
$ctr = 0;
$total = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
      echo "<tr><td>";

      echo $row['id'];

      echo "</td><td>";
      if($ctr == 0 || $tmp != $row['id'])
      {
          echo $row['packetId'];
      }
      echo "</td><td>";

      echo $row['fweight'];

      $total = $total + $row['fweight'];

      echo "</td><td>";
      if($tmp != $row['id'])
      {
          echo $total;
          $total = 0;
          $tmp = $row['id'];
      }
      echo "</td></tr>";
      $ctr++;
  }
```

Comment: +1 for gr8 support , thanks will try this, can you pls guide me on $tmp = ""; $ctr = 0; $total = 0;  ... what are they for

Comment: hey christian , can you please help on my another question which belong same above :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29208997/how-to-get-record-in-while-loop   , please help me