# How to get record in while loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops, while-loop

producttable :

```
id | mid | pid | owgh | nwgh |
1    3      12    1.5    0.6
2    3      12    1.5    0.3
3    3      14    0.6    0.4
4    3      15    1.2    1.1
5    4      16    1.5    1.0
6    4      17    2.4    1.2 
7    3      19    3.0    1.4
8    3      19    3.0    1.2
```

I need result in while loop as **below** : as per mysql query

```
$sql = "SELECT pid,owgh,nwgh from produttable
  WHERE mid = 3 ";
```

**RESULT I WANT AS BELOW :**

```
Product Id  |  Old weight   | New weight 
---------------------------------------
    12            1.5           0.6
    12            1.5           0.3

             Tot: 3.0           0.9
   --------------------------------
    14            0.6           0.4

             Tot: 0.6           0.4
   --------------------------------
    15            1.2          1.1

             Tot: 1.2          1.1
   --------------------------------
    19            3.0          1.4
    19            3.0          1.2

             Tot: 6.0          2.6
```

> `$query = mysql_query($sql);`

```
echo"<table>
     <tr>
       <td> Product Id </td>
       <td> Old Weight </td> 
       <td> New Wight </td>
    </tr>
    ";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query )){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['pid']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['owgh']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['nwgh']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>-----</td>
                  <td>Tot : </td>
                  <td> </td></tr>";
    }
    echo "
    </table>";
```

But result i am getting is as below

```
Product Id  |  Old weight   | New weight 
---------------------------------------
    12            1.5           0.6
   -------------- Tot 
    12            1.5           0.3
   ---------------Tot 
    14            0.6           0.4
   ---------------Tot 
    15            1.2          1.1
   ---------------Tot 
    19            3.0          1.4
   ---------------Tot 
    19            3.0          1.2
```

which i dont want , **i want as below** :

```
Product Id  |  Old weight   | New weight 
---------------------------------------
    12            1.5           0.6
    12            1.5           0.3

             Tot: 3.0           0.9
   --------------------------------
    14            0.6           0.4

             Tot: 0.6           0.4
   --------------------------------
    15            1.2          1.1

             Tot: 1.2          1.1
   --------------------------------
    19            3.0          1.4
    19            3.0          1.2

             Tot: 6.0          2.6
```

**Update : 30/3/2015**

Can i get below result, with sum of each

```
Product Id  |  Old weight   | New weight 
---------------------------------------
    12            1.5           0.6
    12            1.5           0.3

             Tot: 3.0           0.9
   --------------------------------
    14            0.6           0.4

             Tot: 0.6           0.4
   --------------------------------
    15            1.2          1.1

             Tot: 1.2          1.1
   --------------------------------
    19            3.0          1.4
    19            3.0          1.2

             Tot: 6.0          2.6
-----------------------------------
 GRAND TOTAL  =  6.3            5
```

PLEASE NOTE : OLD WEIGHT VALUE HAS REPEAT WEIGHT , HENCE WHILE GRAND TOTAL ITS SINGLE VALUE IS TAKEN

**OR**

```
Product Id  |  Old weight   | New weight 
---------------------------------------
    12            1.5           0.6
                  1.5           0.3

             Tot: 3.0           0.9
   --------------------------------
    14            0.6           0.4

             Tot: 0.6           0.4
   --------------------------------
    15            1.2          1.1

             Tot: 1.2          1.1
   --------------------------------
    19            3.0          1.4
                  3.0          1.2

             Tot: 6.0          2.6
 -----------------------------------
 GRAND TOTAL  =  6.3            5
```

PLEASE NOTE : OLD WEIGHT VALUE HAS REPEAT WEIGHT , HENCE WHILE GRAND TOTAL ITS SINGLE VALUE IS TAKEN

as product id 12, 19 are coming twice hence shown once with its resp value

Please help me, if i am wrong in HTML tr td format please correct me , it not necessary to get in same table tr,td ..i just want my result in above format

Comment: any one here ?? ..please help me with above format in php mysql

Comment: at-least that total weight value ..please any one here ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   $oldsubtotal = 0;
   $newsubtotal = 0;
   $olsgrandtotal = 0;
   $newgrandtotal = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query )){

        if(isset($prev) && ($prev != $row['pid'])){
            echo "<tr><td style='text-align: right'>Total</td><td>".$oldsubtotal."</td><td>".$newsubtotal."</td></tr>"
            echo "<tr><td colspan="3">-----</td></tr>";
            $oldsubtotal = 0;
            $newsubtotal = 0;
        }
        echo "<tr>";            
        echo "<td>.$row['pid'].</td>";
        echo "<td>.$row['owgh'].</td>";
        echo "<td>.$row['nwgh'].</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $oldsubtotal += $row['owgh'];
        $newsubtotal += $row['nwgh'];
        $olsgrandtotal += $row['owgh'];
        $newgrandtotal += $row['nwgh'];
        $prev = $row['pid'];
    }
    echo "<tr><td style='text-align: right'>Grand Total</td><td>".$olsgrandtotal."</td><td>".$newgrandtotal."</td>"
```

Comment: its not only condition  for pid :: result of pid=12 should be in same section please see how i want ..

Comment: yes i tried but table is not coming in proper shape, is coming in same single row all ... please see

Comment: Hey you der ..please check my result how i want ..i am getting result thats pid=12 ins same section but but table structure is broken..please check my result

Comment: your answer works but i get extra "----" row in my starting of result

Comment: product id = 12 only one time and rest of it details as twice i means :
 12   |   1.5   |    0.6  
------------------------
        |   1.5   |    0.3
as 12 is same for boths , show 12 only one time ,,can you help me in this ? in same above your answer... all is perfect just this new features in above u r answer

Comment: u der ? please help me

Comment: hey  , thanks for great support ...please check my Updates Questions ... please help me ..please in this ,, as i am not getting sum value

Comment: @user3209031 do you solve your problem? if have any problem let me know. I was out of internet for three days thats why I cant reply you

Comment: @Sahadat , thanks sir for replying back ,,,, no i am still strugglying to get what i need above ... please check in my question above  Update -- 30/3/2015   --- please help me

Answer (score 1):

`while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query )){
    echo "<td>.$row['pid'].</td>";
    echo "<td>.$row['owgh'].</td>";
    echo "<td>.$row['nwgh'].</td>"; 
    if (isset($before) and $before!=$row['pid']) {
        echo "<td>-----</td>"; 
    } 
    $before= $row['pid'];
}`

Comment: hey  , thanks for great support ...please check my Updates Questions ... please help me ..please in this ,, as i am not getting sum value

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to do it in a single query to avoid loading time of multiple queries and the handle the data in the php side.
So you query must look like this one:

```
$sql = "SELECT pid, owgh, nwgh from produttable WHERE mid = 3 ORDER BY pid";
```

Ordering your results by the pid will help you manage the data in the php side like this:

```
$last_pid = null;
echo '<table class="myTable" border="0">'."\n";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query )) {
    $class = ($last_pid == $row['pid']) ? ' class="same"' : ''; 
    echo '    <tr'.$class.'>'."\n"
        .'        <td>'.$row["pid"].'</td>'."\n"
        .'        <td>'.$row["owgh"].'</td>'."\n"
        .'        <td>'.$row["owgh"].'</td>'."\n"
        .'    </tr>."\n";
    $last_pid = $row["pid"];
}
echo '</table>'."\n";
```

and the style for this class will be:

```
table.myTable { border:0px;}
table.myTable tr { border-bottom:1px solid #000; }
table.myTable tr.same { border-bottom:1px solid #fff; }
```

Comment: please check the result how i want ... thanks for reply

Comment: @user3209031your preferable result its confusing with this <td>-----</td> if you mean <tr><td colspan="3">-----</td></tr> then its easy by reversing the if statement with this line.

Comment: @ nikos , your right i was missing "colspan" , i corrected that but if  i used that " if condition "  first in my while loop( thats same as below anser given by "Md. Sahadat Hossain" ) then its works but i get extra "tr td" row in my starting of result , but if i use " if condition "  at end ( thats same as below answer given by "Héctor Prats" ) then i get result in wrong manner ... ..:(

Comment: u der ? ..please help me

Comment: Then in my example replace: $class = ($last_pid == $row['pid']) ? ' class="same"' : ''; with something like this: echo ($last_pid != $row['pid']) ? "<tr><td colspan='3'>-----</td></tr>" : "";

Comment: hey Nikos , thanks for great support ...please check my Updates Questions ... please help me ..please in this ,, as i am not getting sum value

Comment: at-least help me in getting that Total value of weight ... as per above format